# How to open microphone on File Upload for iPhone

Tags: ios7, media, html5-audio, capture

This below code does work on Android browsers

```
<input type="file" accept="audio/*;capture=microphone" />
```

But for iPhone ( both iOS6 and iOS7 ) , it does not display the microphone recorder , instead it displays **Take Photo or Video** ( ??? ).

If iPhone browsers does not support the microphone capture, do we have anyway to disable the **Take Photo or Video** ? It's really annoying because what I really need is audio files , not photos or videos.

Any help would be appreciated.